# Name for GNU Make $(var:=suffix) syntax

Tags: gnu-make

Evidently, GNU Make supports the syntax `$(var:=suffix)`, which does the same thing as `$(addsuffix suffix,$(var))` as far as I can tell, except that `suffix` can contain `,` in the `:=` version without the use of a variable.

What is this form of expansion called?

Evidently it operates on whitespace-delimited words, producing a new string without modifying the original variable.

This file

```
# Makefile
words=cat dog mouse triangle

$(info $(words:=.ext))
$(info $(words:=.ext))

all:
        @true
```

produces the following when run:

```
$ make
cat.ext dog.ext mouse.ext triangle.ext
cat.ext dog.ext mouse.ext triangle.ext
```

Comment: According to GNU Make's manual, that's called *[substitution reference](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html#SEC61)*.

Comment: Just to be clear, the syntax is actually `$(var:p1=p2)` where `p1` and `p2` are patterns (that is contain `%` characters).  However, there are several special-cases supported: first if there's no `%` character then it's inferred as the first character of both sides of the `=`; e.g. `$(var:X=Y)` is interpreted as `$(var:%X=%Y)`.  Second, if the first pattern doesn't exist at all (your case above) then it's considered to be `%`, so `$(var:=Y)` is interpreted as `$(var:%=%Y)`.